# i generate ng material data table using schematic. i tried replacing their dummy data with data from api, but couldn't get it done

Tags: php, angular, phpmyadmin, angular-material

this is the interface `Tickets[]`

```
export interface Tickets {
    name: string;
    id: number;
  }
```

this is the service i created that should return data fetched from API.. but here i hard coded the data (please someone should help me with right function that will return the data from `api` in `getData()` function)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Tickets } from './ticket.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OpenTicketsService {
  private _url:string = 'assets/data.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  dataRequest():Observable<Tickets[]>{
    return this.http.get<Tickets[]>(this._url);

  }

  getData(){
    //to be replace with the code that will subscribe to `dataRequest()` and return the data
    return [
      {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
      {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
      {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
      {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
      {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
      {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
    ];
  }
```

this is datasource.ts file generated along with angular material data-table

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { OpenTicketsService } from './open-tickets.service';
import { Tickets } from './ticket.model';


export class TicketsTableDataSource extends DataSource<Tickets> {

//this is the function that will return the data from OpenTicketsService and assign it to "data"

 data: Tickets[] = this.ticketService.getData();
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private ticketService:OpenTicketsService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Tickets[]> {
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  disconnect() {}

  private getPagedData(data: Tickets[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  private getSortedData(data: Tickets[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

component.ts file that will display the data on the component.html

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { TicketsTableDataSource } from './tickets-table-datasource';
import { Tickets } from './ticket.model';
import { OpenTicketsService } from './open-tickets.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tickets-table',
  templateUrl: './tickets-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tickets-table.component.scss']
})
export class TicketsTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  constructor(private ticketService:OpenTicketsService) { }
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Tickets>;
  dataSource: TicketsTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new TicketsTableDataSource(this.ticketService);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data source can not be a "service"!!

Futhermore, you needn't use ngAfterView and a View Child to give all properties to your table, see the [example in the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination)

I suppose you want to write some like

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tickerService.dataRequest().subscribe(res=>{
       this.dataSource = new TicketsTableDataSource(res);
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
    })
  }
```

See that it's all under subcribe function

NOTE: If you use `{static:true}` you can asign the paginator in ngOnInit

Comment: thank you very much... it works... though i had to make some changes in "TicketsTableDataSource Class"  to make it accept "res" as parameter and then subscribe to  "ticketService.dataRequest()"  in "ngOnInit" and pass the res as parameter like you did in "ngAfterViewInit"... thanks